# Linux randomly deleted my file while compiling what do I do?

Tags: linux, compilation, gnu, recover

```
gcc -L/root/Desktop - Wall -o prog3.c -pthread -lcopy
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.0: In function '_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my error code. `prog3.c` is nowhere to be found, what on earth happened is there any way to get my file back?? The bold is the command I ran and the rest is the resultant console output

Comment: `-o prog3.c` means that the output of compilation should be put into `prog3.c`. But when the compilation fails it removes the output file.

Comment: Why did you specify the source file as the output file?

Comment: This is what backups are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `-o prog3.c`. `gcc`’s [`-o` option](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.html#output%20file) is used to tell `gcc` which name it should give to the executable it generates. So here, you’re basically asking your compiler to replace your `prog3.c` source file by an executable. Sadly your code is gone...

Comment: ugh, I did not mean to do that. It is all part of a program due tonight for my university, I am a beginner. Guess I better start typing

Comment: Sorry for your work. Barmar is right, you should backup your code! Your editor is probably able to handle that. And don’t forget version-control softwares like Git or SVN. Those allow you to save versions your code and go back to an older version if you messed up.