# Is it possible to recover overwriten file after compilation with `-o` flag, but forgotten argument?

Tags: c, gcc, recover

I ran below command to test a library and forgot to put the executable name after `-o` flag.

```sh
gcc -o bibarreglos.c test2.c
```

After that, `bibarreglos.c` get deleted and throw this error:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

I have the object file, is there any chance to get `bibarreglos.c` back?

Comment: @super or a makefile or other build system...

Comment: Not unless you made a backup beforehand.  You cannot retrieve the original source from the object file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [file has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423990/linux-randomly-deleted-my-file-while-compiling-what-do-i-do) and can't be restored.

Comment: 10/10, no IDE, still deletes your files.